# flash_as3_facebook_api: how to iterate over FacebookSession object that is returned by FacebookDesktop.login

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, loops, flash-builder

in flashbuilder debugger mode, I **can** examine all the props/vals of the FacebookSession object returned by FacebookDesktop.login when I place a *breakpoint* in my loginhandler method.

however, I **cannot** seem to iterate through the FacebookSession object using for...in. I have checked to see if the FacebookSession is dynamic using ObjectUtil.isDynamicObject(...), but it is not, so a for..in should work.

```
public function gf_handle_facebook_login_return( argl_success : Object ,
                                                 argl_failure : Object  ) : void 
  { // IF I ADD breakpoint here, I get a fully populated argl_success object in flashbuilder's Debugger Variables tab.

    trace( "gf_handle_facebook_login_return , A : " + typeof( argl_success ) + " , " + argl_success[ "uid" ] ) ; // works
    trace( "gf_handle_facebook_login_return , C : " + ObjectUtil.isDynamicObject( argl_success ) ) ; // false ... is NOT a dynamic class

    var lvo_FBS : FacebookSession = FacebookSession ( argl_success ) ; // tried it with and without casting
    var lvn_prop :* ;
    for ( lvn_prop  in lvo_FBS) 
      { trace( "gf_handle_facebook_login_return , D : " + lvn_prop   ) ; // is never called
      }
    for each( lvn_prop   in lvo_FBS) 
      { trace( "gf_handle_facebook_login_return , E : " + lvn_prop   ) ; // is never called
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[For in](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for..in) will only loop through dynamic properties and as you said it is not a dynamic.

[Try this example](http://www.learnosity.com/techblog/index.cfm/2008/2/6/AS3--Looping-over-properties-of-a-class)

```
//Get an XML description of this class
//and return the variable types as XMLList with e4x
var varList:XMLList = flash.utils.describeType(myVO)..variable;

for(var i:int; i < varList.length(); i++){
//Show the name and the value
trace(varList[i].@name+':'+ myVO[varList[i].@name]);
}
```

Comment: The_asMan ... that worked ... but I am wondering: does that seem hackish, or would you regard that as an appropriate, robust, dependable method to use for the purpose of digging into a 3rd-party (facebook) vendor's returned object? ... thanks.

Comment: I am sure there is a very good low level reason for it but sorry I do not know. Apparently this option is all you have.

Comment: I would think it is an oversight on FB side. However since you know it is not dynamic then you should just be calling the properties by name.